# Can't run ubuntu off flash drive

Tags: flash, drive

I recently used the universal usb installer to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 onto a formatted 16 GB flash drive.  Once the install was complete, I tried rebooting the machine with the flash drive in my pc, but it went straight to windows.

I tried pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> to change boot options, but under removable, it says no bootable device found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You used "universal usb installer" for OSX?

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is a little vague at the moment. Do you mean to say you used "Universal USB installer" to install Ubuntu on your flash drive? Or did you just create a live USB? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to install Ubuntu on your USB or just run Ubuntu off USB and then install Ubuntu on your computer? Please kindly edit your question and add more information so we can satisfactorily answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible Solutions**

- While inserting your **16 GB USB Drive** press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> to go to **Bios** and under `Boot Device Priority` section move `Removal Drive` to the top. If possible disable other boot options to check if it boots from **USB** or not. Save and restart your system.
- Again While inserting your **16 GB USB Drive** boot from `Universal USB Installer` that you used to install `Ubuntu 12.04.3`, this time chose **`Try Ubuntu`** instead of `Install Ubuntu`. Once started use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to repair your `MBR` or `Grub Menu`.

I hope either 1st or 2nd way will solve your issue..

Comment: I already set to boot order to boot to removable drive first.  When i restarted the computer, it booted normally, it gives me option to start windows 7 or vista.  No option to boot to flash drive.  If it makes a difference, i have 2 partitions, windows 7 and vista on the computer.  Im not sure what else i can do.

Comment: then try to 2nd way..